# Producing dynamic form select field from array and MySQL query

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form containing a select form field. The field options are generated dynamically by a mySQL query and php echo:-

```
    <select name="students" size="10" multiple="multiple">
    <?php
    do {  
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_rsStudents['student_id']?>"><?php echo     $row_rsStudents['student_sname1']?> <?php echo $row_rsStudents['student_sname2']?> <?php     echo $row_rsStudents['student_fname']?>: "</option>
    <?php
    } while ($row_rsStudents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudents));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsStudents);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsStudents, 0);
      $row_rsStudents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudents);
  }
    ?>
    </select>
```

I also have an array which I have exploded and looping:-

```
    <?php
    $studentsids = $row_rsClasses['class_students']; 
    $students = explode(":", $studentsids);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($students); $i++){
    echo "$students[$i]";
    }
    ?>
```

But I want the matching entries to show as selected on the select field. Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you have a list of students that shall be highlighted in the second code fragment in the variable `$students`?

And you have another set of all students which is read in your first code fragment within the while loop?

To display if a specific user is within the array `$students`, you just have to check if the users ID is within this array.

```
if (in_array($row_rsStudents['student_id'], $studentsids)) {
    echo 'selected="selected"';
}
```

This can be embedded within the form code to insert the selected attribute if a specific student is within your array.

Given your second code fragment is executed first:

```
<?php
$studentsids = $row_rsClasses['class_students']; 
// I assume this array contains all IDs that shall be highlighted
$students = explode(":", $studentsids);
?>
```

And your first code fragment then shows all students:

```
<select name="students" size="10" multiple="multiple">
<?php
// why have you used do while? Do you have an existing row before?
// using while(): ... endwhile; is just another style, I prefer it in HTML templates
while ($row_rsStudents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudents):
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_rsStudents['student_id']?>" <?php if (in_array($row_rsStudents['student_id'], $studentsids)) echo 'selected="selected"' ?> >
    <?php echo $row_rsStudents['student_sname1']?>
    <?php echo $row_rsStudents['student_sname2']?>
    <?php echo $row_rsStudents['student_fname']?>
</option>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
// what was this intended to do?
//
//$rows = mysql_num_rows($rsStudents);
//if($rows > 0) {
//    mysql_data_seek($rsStudents, 0);
//    $row_rsStudents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStudents);
//}
?>
</select>
```